# SQL Import data from Access - date issue

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have table `Customers` in my access database which one I'm trying to import into a SQL Server table.

It keeps throwing an exception that it can't export the column `DOB` which is a MS Access date column.

So I did run the query against that table

```
select dob 
from customers   
where year(dob) < 1000
```

I got plenty of results. But when I check the MS Access table like

```
select dob 
from customers   
where isdate(dob) = false
```

Those records won't show up. So function ISDATE consider those dates as valid.

Is there any other workaround to grab all records from table `Customers`, which will actually allow me to insert those records into the SQL Server table?

Note: I need query not tool to do this.

Comment: I'm clueless.  Why are dates with years above 1000 considered invalid?  What do you really want to do?  Sample data and desired results would help.

Comment: @GordonLinoff sorry i thougt less than 1000. Fixed

Comment: @GordonLinoff dates less than 1000 are considered invalid. I don't know how they get into my database but i need sql query which will ignore those dates .

Comment: Can you post some sample data?

Answer (score 0):

It's pretty normal, since ISDATE function looks up for data type (not the value ) and returns boolean result.

On my perspective : What about editing dates lower than 1000 on SQL Server ?

First, feed all the datas to the sql db.
Then, just do whatever you like with adding WHERE DATEFIELD<1000  clause to the end ?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please provide a code or references to back up your answer. We have guidelines on [How to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Actually i did a quick .exe with bulk insert from access to sql and i got detailed exception saying .

> Bulk copy error : SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753
>   12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

So workaround was quite simple then as you can see

```
select dob  from customers    where dob between #1/1/1753# and
#12/31/9999#
```

**Problems** :

Ill miss the records with incorrect dates. Which is not to big issue at the end.

Answer (score 0):

Solution 1

Use a formula that adds 9000 for every date record lower than 1000

Feed all informations to db
Do whatever you like on sql server

Solution 2

Update your exe code :
Check your date field ( if its lower than 1000 or smth)  in your code before insert action , if it is bigger than that feed it.

Comment: I mean, on solution 1 , check do whatever you want with your invalid records, by adding WHERE DATEFIELD>9000 clause to the end.